# How to check column quantity in a filter?

Tags: logstash

I'm receiving logs from a firewall and i want to sort the different types of logs based on the quantity of columns (columns created using cvs with autogenerate on) they have, instead of doing it based on the column values. Something like:

```
                      if number_of_columns == 30:
                                            do this because it's the type of log that has 30 columns
```

Is there some kind of way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the ruby filter to count the number of comma, then store this in a field.

Comment: Thanks you very much !